# What does area density of mm$^{-2}$ mean

Tags: unit-of-measure

I'm not being smart right now but what does an area density of this mean $$10000 \text{ mm}^{-2}$$

Comment: Per unit area, measured in square millimeters

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand, the prefix is at front right and then m^-2? or is it like meter *meter but one of the meters is actually 100 of a meter?

Comment: It is highly likely that it means $(mm)^{-2}$, and not $m(m^{-2})$.

Comment: Per convention $\langle \text{prefix}\rangle m^n$ means $(\langle\text{prefix}\rangle m)^n$, and not $\langle\text{prefix}\rangle(m^n)$, so $mm^{-2}$ is an area that is one millimeter in each direction.

Comment: Also, the two ways of interpreting that expression differ by a factor of 1000. If you have any sense of intuition about the quantities being reported, only one of them ought to be sensible.

Comment: There are ten thousands of something on every square millimeter.

Comment: but why is the 2 negative? wouldn't one millimeter in each direction just be $$mm^2$$?

Comment: is it this $\frac{(1)}{10000mm^2}$ ? $0.0001mm^2$ ? $0.1m^2$?

Comment: It may be $\frac{10000}{\text{mm}^2}$ like in the [inverse square law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)

Comment: It is 10000 of something per square mm. If it was 10000N of force this would be a pressure. If it were 10000 coulombs of charge this would be a surface charge density.

Comment: oh I understand now, don't even know what I was thinking.. thank you

Comment: There is a stray $-$ in my comment, a square that is one millimeter in each direction has an area of $1 mm^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a base to a negative exponent is equivalent to 1/the base to that positive exponent.  $(x^{-2} = \frac{1}{x^2})$.  Acceleration due to gravity is sometimes listed as 9.8m$s^{-2}$ which is 9.8m/$s^2$ or 9.8m/s/s - 9.8 meters per second per second or "per second squared".  Area density is usually mass over area though so a unit is probably needed for the 10000.